# Degree of quasi-projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Why we cannot define the degree of a quasi-projective $k$-variety ($k=\bar k$) $X$ for a given embedding $X\subset \mathbb P^n_k$ ?
If we take any compactification $\bar X$ of $X$, $\bar X\backslash X$ is a projective variety of dimension $\leq dim(X)-1$ so the intersection with a generic linear space of dimension $n-dim(X)$ is empty so why it seems not to be a standard fact?

Comment: Are you asking a question or proposing a definition?

Comment: Good question, indeed... I am wondering why I do not see (so much) the definition of the degree for quasi-projective variety and explaining why I have some trouble understanding why there seems not to be such definition (because the natural one seems to work).

Answer (score 2):

I think this has a sociological, not mathematical, answer.

Whenever you have a structure that could be chosen on a mathematical object, it is handy to have one adjective to say you've made this choice (e.g. **oriented**) and another to say you *could* make this choice (e.g. **orientable**). It's really unfortunate that many, many such structures do *not* have two distinct adjectives to make clear whether the choice has been made.

Your definition is for a quasi-*projectived* variety (since you say "for a given embedding"), and is perfectly well-defined. In my experience the adjective quasiprojective is used to mean quasi-*projectivable* (i.e. there exists an embedding), not quasi-*projectived*. In which case the degree is not well-defined, because it depends on the embedding.

Comment: Quasi-projectivized vs Quasi-projectived?

Comment: I agree, and I would add two more remarks. (1) Of course algebraists and algebraic geometers *do* talk about the degree of quasi-projective varieties.  For instance, the degree of an affine hypersurface, i.e., the total degree of the defining polynomial, is used constantly. (2) The degree of a projective variety is ubiquitous, e.g., in the Hilbert polynomial, in Bezout's theorem for plane curves, etc.  For a quasi-projective variety some of these require care, yet others are not defined, e.g., the vector spaces of global sections of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ may be infinite-dimensional.